# When in history did Purim happen?

Tags: history, historical-figures, megillat-esther

When in history did Purim happen? I understand that there are several opinions that this is based on (who אחשורוש was, whether this was before or after the end of the exile), but I've been unable to find the sources related to it.

Comment: The real question is if you think the Tanakh made sure to clarify the lengths of the full reigns of every Persian king ever. I was never sure why anyone would think that to be the case, though.

Comment: I don't think it did, but the Talmud might have. I know there's a debate in the Gemara on who אחשורוש was but I don't know where and what that would imply.

Comment: The debate is on [RH 3b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=3b&format=pdf), but Chazal's preference to [mix together multiple characters for Midrashic purposes](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33532/759) should never be confused with declarations about history.

Comment: Very, very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34241

Comment: I'd say similar in that it refers to some of the sources I've been looking for. But not the same type of question or the same scope of historical analysis.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2013/02/identifying-achashverosh-and-esther-in.html

Comment: Also relevant and interesting, but not so current or accurate: Yashar's [*Mafteach el Megillat Esther*](http://books.google.com/books?id=IhTxPJcrV9MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97+%D7%90%D7%9C+%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA+%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R-z7UqeONdGGogTO6oGYDQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @msh210 That just asks about only Rishonim's opinions. This asks about when it happened, period. In fact, that question is subsumed under this, no? Shouldn't that one be closed as a dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm _nogea badavar_: don't ask me.

Comment: @msh210 I don't think you are nogea badavar as rep points are pointless (particularly for a mod) so you have nothing to gain or lose.

Comment: @DoubleAA I've continued our conversation to Bam.

Comment: http://www.muncherian.com/ChronologyofEzraNehemiahEsther.pdf ya it's a christian site, but they organized it pretty well

Answer (score 3):

From Codex Judaica pg. 112: they started to rebuild the Second Temple in 3391 Jewish year (-370) Achashverosh the second made his banquet in the year 3395 (-366). In the year 3406 (-355) Mordichai proclaimed the celebration of Purim.

Rabbi Yehuda Landy wrote an in depth book (*[Purim and the Persian Empire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598265199)*) about which Achashverosh was part of the Purim story,and has many archaeological pictures and finds which help determine who and what.

Comment: If you want the Jewish sources I will add them later,they are in the Codex

Comment: Does R Landy agree with the dating of the Codex Judaica?

Comment: I don't remember I read it a while ago,I could check later

Comment: Is this the only opinion, or are there other possibilities based on differences of opinion?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80662

Answer (score 2):

The story of purim happened about 70 years after the destruction of the first temple which happened around year 422 BCE

Comment: Is that as precise as you can get? Can you source either of these numbers?

Answer (score 2):

According to purely Jewish sources, as elucidated by seder olam rabba, Achashverosh lived before Darius the Great, hence purim took place after the beginning of building the temple (during Cyrus) and before it was finished.

Taking into account other historical records it seems that Achashverosh was Xerxes, after Darius the Great, in which case purim took place after completing the Temple.

Both can be read into the pshat of Tanach.