Conservation of Biblical Timepoints?
According to our tradition, several events seem to be occuring within one year one after another. Are there any sources, which explain if there is a midrashic connection?

Time of Akkeida for Yitzchak and the birth of Rivkah, alternatively death of Sarah and birth of Rivkah (according to some manuscripts of Seder Olam)
Blessing of Yaakov by Yitzchak and birth of Leah and Rachel
Death of Rivkah and her nurse Devorah and death of Rachel
Death of Leah and sale of Yosef
Death of Yitzchak and release of Yosef from prison.

Should the question be reformatted as 5 separate questions?
One can show that these calculations follow from the principle of R' Yose ben Chalaphta, a student of R' Akiva. R' Yose's principle states in midrash Seder Olam Rabba 1:2:

לא בא (הכתוב) לסתום אלא לפרש
The Scripture did not come to hide, but to explain.


I'd label this phenomenon the "Conservation of Biblical Timepoints" (as a corollary to the more popular "Conservation of Biblical Personalities" https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33532/759)

@DoubleAA sounds like a good renaming of the question. Thank you.

Avraham going back from Beer Sheva to Chevron (according to Rashi) is an exception.  We learn when it happened from ימים רבים but it seems like nothing else happened at that time

How do we know death of Leah and sale of Yosef? I don't think I've heard that one before.

@Heshy Midrash Seder Olam, same quote as in the answer: אלה תולדת יעקב יוסף בן שבע עשרה שנה (שם לז ב) ובו בפרק מתה לאה, ירד יוסף למצרים. Recall, that Yaakov explains Yosef why did not bury Rachel in Cave of Macpela, where he buried Leah.
