Origin of the Conservation of Biblical Personalities principle
There is a discussion on this site which is defined by a principle of Conservation of Biblical Personalities, when the midrash or aggadeta would quote various persons under the same name. Rabbi Tzvi-Hirsch Chajes in his book "The Student's Guide through the Talmud", chapter XXI The Quoting of Various Persons Under One and the Same Name:

...The Rabbis had the definite principle in their himiletic interpretations of praising, so far as possible, the deeds of the virtuaous and of disparaging the doings of the wicked in every possible way. They further adopted as one of their methods that of calling different personages by one and the same name if they found them akin in any feature of their characters or activities or if they found similarity between any of their actions. Even if where there was only some resemblance in the names of different persons, they blended the two as one ...

Who defined this principle for midrashic literature and how is it related to the principle of R' Yose ben Chalaphta, a student of R' Akiva?

R' Yose's principle in midrash Seder Olam Rabba 1:2 is applied to timing of the events in Tanach:

לא בא (הכתוב) לסתום אלא לפרש
The Scripture did not come to hide, but to explain.

In other words, when an event is happening during a certain time interval as referred by a verse in Tanach, it must refer to either beginning or the end of the interval, same place, Seder Olam Rabba 1:2, towards the end:

Rabbi Yose said: Ever was a great prophet that he called his son Peleg ("split") "because in his days the earth was split" (Bereshis 10:25). You cannot say this happened when Peleg was born since his younger brother Yoqtan had 13 families as his descendants at the Language split. You cannot say that this happened during Peleg's middle life since the Scripture does not come to hide but to explain. Therefore, the verse must mean that the split occured during Peleg's last year of life.


The question is still not very clear. Can you explain why your citations would be related?

@shmosel it is not clear to me. Double AA stated so in the comment to my other question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/146335/conservation-of-biblical-timepoints, and I am trying to figure this out.

@YDJ thanks for doing this

Difference between Rabbi Yose and the first case is Rabbi Yose is in rules of pshat and first case is in realm of drush.

@N.T. that would be a good answer even though Seder Olam is also midrash.

It may contain derash but this rule is for pshat. That is also how Rashi uses it in Chumash. Rashi almost never brings the first approach, probably because too far from pshat.

@N.T. I’m not sure why you say Rashi almost never uses this approach. A few examples from Sefer Bereishit alone: Naama = Mrs Noach, Yiskah = Sarai, Yehudit bat Be’eri = Oholivamah bat Anah, Poti Phera = Potiphar.

@JoelK it is very hard to accept that different names always mean different people. For example, Eisav was also Edom. So there were cases of people having several names.

@YDJ that's certainly true, but the four examples I list above have very little reason in peshat to assume that they are the same person with two names

@JoelK Naama needs a reason in pshat for why she is mentioned at all. And Sarah is said later to be Avraham's niece, so she had to be either Yiskah or Milka. Rashi does not say some of the famous ones like Haman=Memuchan or Pinchas=Eliyahu (he even references a Midrash that says Eliyahu was from Shevet Gad) or Lavan=Bilaam.

Difference between Rabbi Yose and the first case is Rabbi Yose is in rules of pshat and first case is in realm of drush.
